# Changing the hostname for tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, hostname

Apparently, while running tests in Rails, the hostname is "www.example.com". If I run root_url in a test it'll return "http://www.example.com/".

Since I'm doing an app that requires another hostnames, is there a way to change the default hostname to something else, so I don't have to specify it every time I generate a URL in the tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer is no, in the test code, you have to specify the host when calling url helpers.

Answer (score 2):

Path/url helpers take hostname from request object. So in test you can do something like this:

```
request.host = "another-domain.com"
```

Comment: That's only for the request, it doesn't change the result of calling root_url in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think in you can do something like this in your config/environments/test.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

ps this is untested for now. I know i did something like this but once but the code is on my computer at work. I will check it tomorrow if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends how do you test. For example, if you're using Capybara for your test suite you can specify `default_host`